# Fetch rows and count them in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure that join three tables to fetch province title from it's table. This is my code:

```
BEGIN
    select TbProvince.title, count(TbProvince.title) as cnt
    from TbProvince
    where TbProvince.provinceId IN (select TbCustomerUser.provinceId 
                                    from TbCustomerUser INNER JOIN
                                         TbDeals
                                         on TbCustomerUser.UserId = TbDeals.sellerUserID
                                    where TbDeals.buyerUserID = 1
                                   )
    group by TbProvince.title
end
```

*Description:* I have three tables for deals, customers and provinces. I want to retrieve province title and the count of that for customers that were sellers.
The above code have no problem, but only return 1 as a count. The number of customers is more than one.
Can anybody help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform the `JOIN` with `customer` table. If you use semi join (expressed by `IN` construct in your case) then you avoid duplicates that are expected in your case.

```
SELECT TbProvince.title,
       COUNT(TbProvince.title) AS cnt
FROM TbProvince 
JOIN TbCustomerUser ON TbProvince.provinceId = TbCustomerUser.provinceId
JOIN TbDeals ON TbCustomerUser.UserId = TbDeals.sellerUserID
WHERE TbDeals.buyerUserID = 1
GROUP BY TbProvince.title;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as:

You won't need the subselect. Just join all three tables and you'll receive your desired result.

```
    SELECT TbProvince.title, 
           count(TbProvince.title) as cnt 
      FROM TbProvince
     INNER JOIN TbCustomerUser 
        ON TbProvince.provinceId = TbCustomerUser.provinceId
     INNER JOIN TbDeals  
        ON TbCustomerUser.UserId = TbDeals.sellerUserID
       AND TbDeals.buyerUserID   = 1
  GROUP BY TbProvince.title
```

Why did your solution not work?
You subselect will return a "list" of `provinceIDs` from `TbCustomerUser` combinated with `TbDeals` with your restriction `TbDeals.buyerUserID = 1`.
The outer select will now return all rows from TbProvince IN this list.
But it's not returning a row for each Customer who had a deal.
That's why you have to `JOIN` all three tables at once.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is filtering the rows of `TbProvince` and then aggregating that table -- and only that table.

Instead, you want to join the tables together to count the *customers* not the *provinces*.  The query is much simpler to write and read if you use table aliases:

```
select p.Title, count(*)
from TbCustomerUser cu join
     TbDeals d
     on cu.UserId = d.sellerUserID join
     TbProvince p
     on p.provinceId = cu.provinceId
where d.buyerUserID = 1
group by p.Title;
```